# Table Design for User Selectable Schedule and Select Using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am creating a scheduling application that allows employees to input their desired schedule which is stored in a table. The current design I'm looking at is below using SQL 2008 R2.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule] (
    [EmpNum] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Length] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Reason] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [EmpNum] ASC,
        [Start] ASC
    )
)
```

A few things to note

- A user may have entered no schedule for a specific date range and still want to see their name listed but with no schedule
- A user may select nothing for a day in a week, but select something for other days
- **Start** is the beginning of the shift
- **Length** is the number of hours a shift is, may vary WILDLY from day to day and person to person
- The **Reason** column is for what has been selected by the user (W - Work, P - PTO, etc)

Here is sample data

```
EmpNum     Start                   Length                                  Reason
---------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------- ------
000001     2012-08-02 09:00:00.000 12.00                                   W
000001     2012-08-04 08:00:00.000 9.50                                    P
000002     2012-08-02 08:30:00.000 10.00                                   W
000002     2012-08-03 19:00:00.000 12.00                                   W
000003     2012-08-03 08:00:00.000 8.00                                    P
```

The output I desire is something like this

```
EmpNum     [0]    [1]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]    [6]
---------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
000001     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   W      NULL   P
000002     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   W      W      NULL
000003     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   P      NULL
```

I've never used a `PIVOT` query before since we just upgraded from SQL 2000, so bear with me. I've constructed the below query which fails with the below error and I'm stuck.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Query

```
declare @FirstDayOfWeek date
set @FirstDayOfWeek = '7/29/2012'

select EmpNum,
@FirstDayOfWeek [0],
dateadd(day, 1, @FirstDayOfWeek) [1],
dateadd(day, 2, @FirstDayOfWeek) [2],
dateadd(day, 3, @FirstDayOfWeek) [3],
dateadd(day, 4, @FirstDayOfWeek) [4],
dateadd(day, 5, @FirstDayOfWeek) [5],
dateadd(day, 6, @FirstDayOfWeek) [6]
from Schedule
pivot (
    max(Reason)
    for Start in ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) as Pvt
```

Any thoughts on how to best implement this or how badly wrong I am here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to PIVOT your data based on the Day of the Week 1-7.  I suggest a slight change to this to get it to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select EmpNum,
        reason,
        datepart(dw, start) as DyOfWk
    from #Schedule
) s
pivot (
    max(Reason)
    for dyofwk in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) as Pvt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/111f1/1)

Results:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfect. I believe I understand how these work now. Thank you for the quick help.